# Process.start is finding the wrong python version

Tags: c#, .net, exec

I have the below

```
protected void RunPython(string scriptname)
{
    var p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = @"python";
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = scriptname;
    p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
    p.Start();
    Assert.True(p.WaitForExit(10000));
}
```

When I call it (Currently debug build from VS) it calls python 2.2.. (I have 2.2, 2.6, 2.7, 3.3 & 3.4 installed)

In my PATH there is only 3.4. If I call "python --version" or "Python.exe --version" from a command prompt it tells me i'm using 3.4

Where is .Net finding 2.2? / How do I stop it?

Edit: Addition

```
PATH (User): C:\Tcl\bin;C:\Users\[UserName]\AppData\Roaming\npm;%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap
PATH (System): C:\Perl64\site\bin;C:\Perl64\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin;C:\Python34;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim74;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin
```

Thanks

Comment: Please post your entire path, along with all punctuation marks that it may have. Are you starting this from a command line, or from VS?

Comment: I would fully qualify the location of Python to avoid this problem. In general, having dependencies on system variables like this is not very robust, because users could accidentally break your system by updating the `PATH` variable.

Comment: The problem is this is in a testsuite. It needs to run on all the developers machines and the debian/mono based test server.

Comment: You could use your own environment variable, rather than the path. Say, `@"%test_python%\\python"`.

Comment: Found the issue - A Registry entry under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\Python.exe

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\Python.exe

Appears Process doesn't have knowledge of the PATH, or if it does it uses it secondarily